# How to switch between different objects with the same geometry and material

Tags: three.js

I have two objects in THREE.js with the same geometry and material but one is a pointcloud and one is the meshed counterpart, like this:

```
var particles = new THREE.PointCloud( geometry, shaderMaterial );
var meshes = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, shaderMaterial);
```

I want to switch between the particles and meshes when viewing the scene by

```
scene.add(particles);
scene.remove(meshes);
```

OR

```
scene.remove(particles);
scene.add(meshes);
```

But errors comes in three.js when executing the above commands. I am wondering how can I implement such kind of switch between pointcloud and meshes with the same geometry and material?

Comment: Hi please also provide code for the definition of `geometry` and `shaderMaterial`

Comment: posting the errors you get will also probably be helpful.

Comment: have you tried just settings the `visible` property on the objects rather than removing and adding them?

Comment: +1 for visible, would probably perform better.

Comment: The problem is: I cannot add the two objects with the same geometry and materials to the scene so I can't see the visibility of the two objects.

Comment: The code of the geometry is from the ply loader (http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_ply) as var geometry = event.content;
For shadermaterial: 
shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
  uniforms: uniforms,
  attributes: attributes,
  vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexshader' ).textContent,
  fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentshader' ).textContent,
  alphaTest: 0.9,
  side: THREE.DoubleSide,
 } );

Comment: Error is from the render function and it comes from three.js: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in three.min.js:560.